# Maven settings.xml property is not resolved in transitive dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies, settings

I have a property in settings.xml,

> fwk.version = "2.0.001"

Other side, a multiproject with two projects, earmodule and ejbmodule.

ejbmodule has a dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>shared-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>proxi2.fwk.comuns</artifactId>
        <version>${fwk.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

and it's works correctly

but earmodule has a dependency on ejbmodule

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>projectGroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejbmodule</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and it tries to solve the dependency and it fails:

[WARNING] Missing POM for shared-lib:proxi2.fwk.comuns:pom:${fwk.version}

instead trying to download

shared-lib:proxi2.fwk.comuns:pom:2.0.001

It happens when i try to package parent project.

Looks like a bug in Maven3

Do you know why?

Thx

**EDIT:**

Our solution/workaround has been defining in parent pom a dependencyManagement section because in this level works ok.

Then in subproject ejbmodule, we have an "independent version" dependency because uses parent definition in dependencyManagement

settings.xml:

```
<fwk.version>2.0.001</fwk.version>
```

parent pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>shared-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>proxi2.fwk.comuns</artifactId>
        <version>${fwk.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

ejbmodule pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>shared-lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>proxi2.fwk.comuns</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

I hope this would help other

Comment: Does it work if the same property is specified in your parent pom instead of *settings.xml*?  Also, are you trying *mvn package* or *mvn install*?  Does the latter work?

Comment: It's a package and it doesn't work too if i specify it in parent pom.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is an [open](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3782) maven bug related to this.

Comment: Unfortunately, the links is broken, it should be that one https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3782. The problem is open from 2014 and it has been closed without resolution. So bad! See here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/The+Great+JIRA+Cleanup+of+2014

Answer (score 0):

I see a similar problem only in a different situation. I used a property to define a URL where to send my created javadocs like this

```
<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <id>javadocs</id>
        <name>Java Documentation</name>
        <url>scp://${javadocs.url}/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
```

And of course I set the property in my settings.xml in a profile

```
</settings>
    .
    .
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>develop</id>
            <properties>
                <environment.type>develop</environment.type>
                <javadocs.url>javadocs.server.com/home/javadocs/javadocs</javadocs.url>
            </properties>
            .
            .
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>develop</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

The `distributionManagement` section was put into the pom of project **parent** which was used as parent in the project **child**

When doing

```
mvn site-deploy
```

in the **child** project I got this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:deploy (default-deploy)
>   on project child: Error uploading site: Cannot connect. Reason:
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: ${javadocs.url} -> [Help 1]

So clearly the property was not set anymore.

The only workaround I can think of is to put the properties in the parent pom. I know this is terrible because if you want to change them you need to redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

Following the fact that this issue seems due a bug of Maven and it is apparently not expected to be fixed soon, I have found a simple workaround that seems work for me.

Instead that defining a variable with dot notation like fwk.version, try a snake case like fwk_version. I  tried it tp define in my settings.xml url of repositories  and it works.

Reference: I found this from this post http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Settings-properties-not-resolved-when-used-in-repository-element-td5746974.html

I hope it can help also in transitive dependencies.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please write a comment instead.

Comment: @Zoe  you're right, I created a new answer when I had would like to only comment the previous answer. My bad.